# Unable to read depth buffer from Compute shader

Tags: hlsl, directx-11

I am unable to read depth buffer from compute shader.

I am using this in my hlsl code.

```
Texture2D<float4> gDepthTextures : register(t3);
// tried this.
//Texture2D<float> gDepthTextures : register(t3);
// and this.
//Texture2D<uint> gDepthTextures : register(t3);
// and this.
//Texture2D<uint4> gDepthTextures : register(t3);
```

And doing this to read the buffer.

```
outputTexture[dispatchThreadId.xy]=gDepthTextures.Load(int3(dispatchThreadId.xy,0));
```

And I am detaching depth buffer from render target.

```
ID3D11RenderTargetView *nullView[3]={NULL,NULL,NULL};
        g_pImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets( 3, nullView, NULL );
```

Still I am getting this error in output.

```
*D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::Dispatch: The Shader Resource View dimension declared in the shader code (TEXTURE2D) does not match the view type bound to slot 3 of the Compute Shader unit (BUFFER).  This mismatch is invalid if the shader actually uses the view (e.g. it is not skipped due to shader code branching). [ EXECUTION ERROR #354: DEVICE_DRAW_VIEW_DIMENSION_MISMATCH]*
```

This is how I am creating shader resource view.

```
// Create depth stencil texture
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC descDepth;
ZeroMemory( &descDepth, sizeof(descDepth) );
descDepth.Width = width;
descDepth.Height = height;
descDepth.MipLevels = 1;
descDepth.ArraySize = 1;
descDepth.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_TYPELESS;
descDepth.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
descDepth.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
descDepth.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
descDepth.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
descDepth.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
descDepth.MiscFlags = 0;
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateTexture2D( &descDepth, NULL, &g_pDepthStencil );
if( FAILED( hr ) )
    return hr;

// Create the depth stencil view
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC descDSV;
ZeroMemory( &descDSV, sizeof(descDSV) );
descDSV.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT;
descDSV.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
descDSV.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateDepthStencilView( g_pDepthStencil, &descDSV,     &g_pDepthStencilView );
if( FAILED( hr ) )
    return hr;

//  Create depth shader resource view.
D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc;
ZeroMemory(&srvDesc,sizeof(D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC));
srvDesc.Format=DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT;
srvDesc.ViewDimension=D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
srvDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip=0;
srvDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels=1;


hr=g_pd3dDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(g_pDepthStencil,&srvDesc,&g_pDepthSRV);
if(FAILED(hr))
    return hr;
```

I have tried all the formats mentioned [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26687/what-are-the-valid-depthbuffer-texture-formats-in-directx-11-and-which-are-also) in combination with the hlsl texture formats float, float4, uint, uint4 with no success. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT by DXGI_FORMAT_R32_FLOAT for your shader resource view, since you use R32_Typeless, you have a floating point buffer.

Texture2D gDepthTextures will be the one you need to load or sample the depth later.

Also it looks like that your texture is not bound properly to your compute shader (since runtime tells you you have a buffer bound in there).

Make sure you have:

```
immediateContext->CSSetShaderResources(3,1,g_pDepthSRV);
```

Called before your dispatch.

As a side note, to debug those type of issues, you can also call [CSGetShaderResources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476398%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and other equivalent), in order to check what's bound in your pipeline before your call.

Comment: still getting "D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::Dispatch: The Shader Resource View dimension declared in the shader code (TEXTURE2D) does not match the view type bound to slot 3 of the Compute Shader unit (BUFFER).  This mismatch is invalid if the shader actually uses the view (e.g. it is not skipped due to shader code branching). [ EXECUTION ERROR #354: DEVICE_DRAW_VIEW_DIMENSION_MISMATCH]"

Comment: Edited answer, seems your depth is not bound prior to dispatch (the float format is still needed for your sampling by the way).

Comment: I already am doing this just before dispatch.    "g_pImmediateContext->CSSetShaderResources(3,1,&g_pDepthSRV);"

Comment: I used CSGetShaderResource, returned pointer is different than what i passed initially. don't know how to compare two SRVs. tried this too "ID3D11ShaderResourceView *tmp[]={g_pDepthSRV};
   g_pImmediateContext->CSSetShaderResources(3,1,tmp);" still returning different pointer.

Comment: MM maybe g_pDepthSRV is overwritten somewhere in your code?

Comment: I used CSGetShaderResource on other bound textures which i know are working and they returned pointers matching what i passed. this suggests there is an issue with setting shader resource. But i still dont know whats the issue.

Comment: You were right texture 3 was being modified by somewhere else in the code. While debugging with vs12 graphics mode I discovered this. It was difficult to observe as only the last change was visible due to optimization. Thanks